# Уникализировать js код чтоб его можно было дублировать

Tags: javascript, html

Вопрос довольно простого уровня, но я сейчас изучаю javascript.
Как сделать чтоб блок .counter можно было дублировать? Сейчас кнопки +/- работают только когда на странице один блок .counter. Если продублировать и добавить 2 блока на страницу, то кнопки у них не будут работать. Подскажите пожалуйста решение.

```js
const minusBtn = document.querySelector('.minus-btn'),
      count = document.querySelector('.counter-input'),
      plusBtn = document.querySelector('.plus-btn');

let countNum = 1;

minusBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (count.value > 1) {
      countNum -= 1;
      count.value = countNum; 
    }
});

plusBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    countNum += 1;
    count.value = countNum;
});
```

```css
.counter {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.counter input {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.minus-btn, .plus-btn {
  font-size: 26px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter">
  <button class="minus-btn">-</button>
  <input type="text" value="1" inputmode="numeric" pattern="/d+" class="counter-input">
  <button class="plus-btn">+</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том что querySelector() находит только один элемент на странице. Когда он нашел первый попавшийся ему элемент он прекращает поиск и возвращает его. Для решения этой задачи Вам необходимо воспользоваться querySelectorAll() он находит все искомые элементы на странице и возвращает коллекцию найденных элементов. Ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```js
const minusBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.minus-btn'),
count = document.querySelectorAll('.counter-input'),
plusBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.plus-btn');



for (let i = 0, n = minusBtn.length; i < n; ++i){
    minusBtn[i].addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        if(count[i].value > 1){
            let sum = +count[i].value;
            sum -= 1;
            count[i].value = sum;
        }
    });
}

for (let i = 0, n = plusBtn.length; i < n; ++i){
    plusBtn[i].addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        let sum = +count[i].value;
        sum += 1;
        count[i].value = sum;
   });
}
```

```css
.counter {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.counter input {
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid lightgray;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.minus-btn, .plus-btn {
    font-size: 26px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border: 0;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter">
    <button class="minus-btn" id="btn-minus">-</button>
    <input type="text" value="1" inputmode="numeric" pattern="/d+" class="counter-input">
    <button class="plus-btn" id="btn-plus">+</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="counter">
    <button class="minus-btn" id="btn-minus">-</button>
    <input type="text" value="1" inputmode="numeric" pattern="/d+" class="counter-input">
  <button class="plus-btn" id="btn-plus">+</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="counter">
    <button class="minus-btn" id="btn-minus">-</button>
    <input type="text" value="1" inputmode="numeric" pattern="/d+" class="counter-input">
    <button class="plus-btn" id="btn-plus">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Помимо `querySelector`, который находит только один элемент по указанному селектору, существует еще `querySelectorAll`, который уже находит все элементы по указанному селектору. Тогда уже будет массив элементов, и можно работать со всеми найденными элементами.

Поскольку при наличии большого количества блоков придется вешать очень много обработчиков, есть возможность сократить их количество за счет навешивания на родительские блоки, а внутри обработчика проверять, что является целью клика. Это работает благодаря свойству событий "всплывать" ([подробнее](https://learn.javascript.ru/bubbling-and-capturing)).

```js
const counterBlock = document.querySelectorAll('.counter'), // находим все блоки .counter
      minusBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.minus-btn'),
      count = document.querySelectorAll('.counter-input'),
      plusBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.plus-btn');


counterBlock.forEach((item, key) => { // перебираем каждый блок .counter ... 
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => { // ... и вешаем обработчик клика
    if (e.target == minusBtn[key] && count[key].value > 1) { // проверяем, является ли кнопка "-" с индексом, как у родительского блока, целью 
      count[key].value--;
    } else if (e.target == plusBtn[key]) { // проверяем, является ли кнопка "+" с индексом, как у родительского блока, целью  
      count[key].value++;
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.counter {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.counter input {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.minus-btn, .plus-btn {
  font-size: 26px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter">
  <button class="minus-btn">-</button>
  <input type="text" value="1" inputmode="numeric" pattern="/d+" class="counter-input">
  <button class="plus-btn">+</button> 
</div>
<div class="counter">
  <button class="minus-btn">-</button>
  <input type="text" value="2" inputmode="numeric" pattern="/d+" class="counter-input">
  <button class="plus-btn">+</button> 
</div>
<div class="counter">
  <button class="minus-btn">-</button>
  <input type="text" value="3" inputmode="numeric" pattern="/d+" class="counter-input">
  <button class="plus-btn">+</button> 
</div>
<div class="counter">
  <button class="minus-btn">-</button>
  <input type="text" value="4" inputmode="numeric" pattern="/d+" class="counter-input">
  <button class="plus-btn">+</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Если добавить в кнопку +/- какой-то span внутрь и он займет всю его область, то получается клик уже происходит по спану и не срабатывает. Как это исправляется?

Comment: я если что не минусовал ваш ответ